# Problema com escopo dos Componentes do Angular 2 com a importação de Javascripts externos

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou com um problema e acredito que o mesmo está relacionado ao escopo dos Componentes no Angular 2.

Primeiramente, gostaria de comentar sobre a divisão do projeto. Ele está dividido em cinco componentes, o App, Menu-left, Menu-header, Content e Footer-Component.

Index:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Frontend</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
        <div class="main_container">
          <app-root></app-root>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

O `<app-root></app-root>` é o principal e é composto pelos módulos:

`app.component.ts:`

```
<menu-left></menu-left>
<menu-header></menu-header>
<content></content>
<footer-component></footer-component>
```

Dentro de cada um há um conteúdo HTML que será apresentado ao usuário, com o o menu no topo (menu-header), um menu na esquerda (menu-left), etc...

O problema que estou tendo é em relação ao carregamento do Javascript na apresentação desses dados, ou seja, os Javascripts funcionam para o `Menu-Header`, no qual é apresentado um `menu drop-down` com os efeitos 100%. Porém, o mesmo não ocorre para o `Menu-Left`, em que também há um `menu drop-down`.

O que eu testei foi o seguinte: juntei todos os HTMLs (do menu-left, menu-header, content, footer) e os inseri diretamente na página principal (`index.html`) e o mais frustrante foi que funcionou tudo, com 100% dos efeitos carregados dos Javascripts que importei.

Vale ressaltar que estou usando o Angular-CLI e estou importando os Styles e Javascripts da seguinte maneira:

angular-cli.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "frontend"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../../../target/frontend",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/production/css/maps/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/production/less/custom.css"        
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/build/js/custom.min.js"
    ...
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Gostaria de uma sugestão que possa me ajudar a encontrar esse problema que eu acredito ser de 'escopo', pois foi o que mais me fez sentido.

Valeeu!!

Comment: Alexandre, tudo bem?<br>
Você fez o import e declarou os components no "app.module"?
<br>
Tive um problema parecido ontem, quando fui revisar o código, percebi que não tinha importado e declarado um componente.

Comment: Sim, eu importei os módulos e os adicionei no imports.
Apenas o AppComponent deixei no declaration e no bootstrap.

Comment: Alexandre, no declarations do "app.module.ts" você precisa declarar os componentes novos também, por exemplo, isso aqui:
"@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HelloWorldComponent,
    UserItemComponent,
    UserListComponent,
    ArticleComponent
  ]"

Comment: Na verdade não, pois eu já incluo os módulos dos mesmos e quando insiro novamente, há um compilation error, mostrando que estou definindo duas vezes a component.

Comment: @AlexandreBarreiroNeto bota aí no post o `app.module.ts`