# Problemas com importação de script em Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, script

Estou com um pequeno problema com script e acredito ser escopo de component.
Eu uso um script pra scroll no firefox, pois no chrome funciona normalmente o anchorScrolling.
O problema é que se eu chamo na rota onde tem o Nav bar e footer, nas rotas filhas o script não funciona, ai preciso adiciona-lo em cada filho. Até aí tudo bem. O problema é que em cada rota que carrego ele add o mesmo script novamente.

Ou seja, se o usuário navegar em 4 rotas diferentes, terei 4 vezes o mesmo script e assim qdo clico em algo pra dar scroll a função é executada 4 vezes. Alguém sabe de uma alternativa?

A divisão do meu projeto é assim, App, Site component (onde chamo header, router-outlet e footer), e demais rotas como Home e Sobre por exemplo.

faço assim:

```
export class InjectScript {

    LoadScript(url: string) {
        const body = <HTMLDivElement>document.body;
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.innerHTML = '';
        script.src = url;
        script.async = false;
        script.defer = true;
        body.appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

e no onInit dos componentes:

```
ngOnInit( ) {
    this.inject = new InjectScript();
    this.inject.LoadScript('assets/js/funcoes.js');
    // obs: funcoes.js é o script que contem meu scroll
  }
```

Obs.: encontrei essa outra pergunta que me parece o mesmo problema que tenho, porém não tem nenhuma sugestão de solução. [Problema com escopo dos Componentes do Angular 2 com a importação de Javascripts externos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207054/problema-com-escopo-dos-componentes-do-angular-2-com-a-importa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-javascripts)

ATUALIZANDO:
Descobri que quando eu coloco um evento de click chamando uma função que não existe, aparece o erro no console porem funciona o scroll normalmente no Firefox. exemplo: (click)="bolinha()"

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink] = "['/sobre']" fragment="meuId"(click)="bolinha()"  ></a>
```

Porém ainda não sei como fazer sem aparecer o erro.

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa minha resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304485/scripts-angular/304488#304488

Comment: @EduardoVargas olhei sua resposta aqui, porém injetar o script não está sendo o problema, e sim que ele funciona apenas para a rota que foi injetado. De forma que tenho que fazer para todas as rotas. Exemplo, importo no Home, depois importo novamente no About, e assim sucessivamente. Fazendo assim funciona mas carrega várias vezes o mesmo <script>.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a melhor opção, mas você pode verificar se já tem a sua função declarada antes de injetar novamente no onInit()

```
if( typeof nomeDaSuaFuncao == 'function')
{
    this.inject = new InjectScript();
    this.inject.LoadScript('assets/js/funcoes.js');

}
```

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Eu até tentei fazer dessa forma mas não sei como colocar o "nomeDaMinhaFuncao" sem apresentar erro. Ou entendi errado ou meu TypeScript não "enxerga" minhas funções dentro do script (js).

Answer (score 0):

No `angular-cli.json` coloque a seguinte string

src/main/frontend/src/assets

```
      "scripts": [
        "..."
        "../src/assets/js/custom.js" <~ arquivo adicionado
         ...
     ],
```

Assim o arquivo ficará visível para todo o sistema.

Comment: Já tentei fazer dessa forma, porém na página home funciona por exemplo, mas nas outras rotas como 'Sobre' e 'Servicos' por exemplo, não funciona. O mais engraçado é que se eu estiver em uma dessas rotas e inspecionar o código o script está lá. O que me leva a pensar mais uma vez que tem algo a ver com escopo.

Comment: Você tem alguma demonstração de como esse arquivo é usado ? Você chama a função dentro do arquivo ?

Comment: Se refere ao script? 

`$('.scroll-page').click(function () {
  var $doc = $('html, body');

 if (this.hash !== "") {
   $doc.animate({
  scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
   }, 500);
   return false;
 }
});`

Comment: atualizei a pergunta, se possível dê uma olhada por favor.